# Regex with Javascript getting text between two square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, square-bracket

I have some text with several special charakters in it and i want to get the text between the special charakters. 
I am gogin fin with something like this:

```
=== TestText ===
```

This works with the regex:

```
/(?:^|\s)=== (.*?) ===(?:\s|$)/g
```

There i get `TestText`.
But now my Problem is when i want to get some text between two square brackets.

```
[[This is a text]]
```

with the regex : `/(?:^|\s)\[\[ (.*?) \]\](?:\s|$)/g` i don't get any result. 
can you help me ?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Remember, spaces in the pattern match spaces in the input string. Your pattern *would* have matched the input of `[[ This is a text ]]`

Comment: oh thank you .. i should take a break -.- can't see the simplest things. no i'ts working

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
\[+(.*?)\]+
```

and grab captured group #1. This matches 1+ of `[`s followed by 0 or more of any characters followed by 1+ of `]` characters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR1dD6/8)

Comment: the problem with both solutions is that if i have [[Text]] and [[[text2]]] i get Text and [text2 as result.

Comment: You didn't specify in question that you have the `[[[` and `]]]`. Can you have `[[[[` and `]]]]` also?

Comment: You can use: `/\[+(.*?)\]+/g`

Comment: Did this work for you?